# Is it possible to return result asynchronously in WCF server (similar to MVC AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment)

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am creating a WCF service that needs to call few other services inside. If I do it simple way then the execution time will be a sum of all of the calls to other service (plus some overhead). What I want to do is to call the services asynchronously so that I can return the result when I get all of the data. I know that in MVC it is possible by calling `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment()` and then `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement()` (that will run in another thread). Is there a way to do something similar in WCF?

Comment: If it's acceptable to call the service on the *client* asynchronously, I believe WCF 4.5's `svcutil` generates asynchronous method calls. See [Task-based Async Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx).

Comment: This is the asynchronous client to server call you are talking about and I guess it is not important for what's happening inside the server...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question?